# Not finding Dependencies on react package testing locally

Tags: reactjs, node.js, typescript, npm

I Have [this](https://github.com/vsla/react-analytics-tracker) npm package, is a React Package using Typescript

I started do debug it locally using `npm link` in a fresh react project

But, it gets me this error

[image: React error using react node local package]

Maybe it is not reading the packages, but i don't figure out how to do it!

This is the code of the package

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'

interface AnalyticsData {
  pageViews: Record<string, number>
}

const analyticsData: AnalyticsData = {
  pageViews: {},
}

const AnalyticsTracker: React.FC = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const path = window.location.pathname

    // Update page view statistics
    analyticsData.pageViews[path] = (analyticsData.pageViews[path] || 0) + 1

    // You can add additional logic to track other events here

    console.log('Analytics Data:', analyticsData)
  }, [])

  return null
}

export default AnalyticsTracker
```

Running the yarn run build with tsc in a dist folder
Should be using webpack? How?

Here is the dependencies in package.json of the project that i'm linking the package

```
"dependencies": {
  "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
  "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
  "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
  "react": "^18.2.0",
  "react-analytics-tracker": "file:../react-analytics-tracker",
  "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
  "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
  "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
}
```

For some reason, when i delete node modules, the package starts to run in the project, but the package start to popup some errors related to not having react as a dependency

```
src/App.tsx:2:34 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'react' or its corresponding type declarations
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'


Found 1 error in src/App.tsx:2
```

But the package start to work.

Thanks for any help!!

Answer (score 0):

In your npm package, React is listed as a peerDependency. This means you have to install it in the project that is importing the package.

In the project where you have imported react-analytics-tracker, also please add the react dependency. Then npm install, and you should be able to resolve the error.

Comment: I have updated the question. I have react in the project dependencies, i just created a fresh new react project using create-react-app. And still not working.